# When is it safe to use the Anvil of Krong?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Is there a way to know whether an item will be enchanted or cursed by an anvil of Krong?

At first it happened to me when I used the same item on three different anvils. Recently it has also happened on the second anvil. Is there a rule for this? Or is it just random chance whenever you use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not tied to the number of times you've used a particular item on the anvil.  There's a random chance each time you drop an item, regardless of what happened to that item previously.  I've had things cursed the first time I've dropped them, for instance.

The [Dredmor wiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Anvil_of_Krong) says that it's 2/7 chance of a curse, and a 5/7 chance of a blessing.

I'm always torn between using a really good item on it, in the hopes that it gets better, or using a kind of "meh" item in the hopes that it either becomes good or destroying it won't matter.  Frequently what I'll do is try to use something that I have a duplicate of, or at least a backup for that slot.  That way if it gets better, it's a win, and if it gets worse, oh well, I've got a backup.

Comment: The wiki states: "This does not apply to the character's first use of an Anvil of Krong, which will never result in a curse." and so far my interpretation is that normal quality items cannot be cursed. ie. you cannot curse a normal item, but you can curse an item which is not normal. http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Anvil_of_Krong

Comment: Nevermind, I just got a curse on a normal quality item on the first go. I'm not really sure if the section I quoted above really holds any merit.

Answer (score -2):

I'd take  "This does not apply to the character's first use of an Anvil of Krong, which will never result in a curse." to mean the first time a new character uses any anvil, not each anvil. So the very first time you use any anvil, you're safe. After that, there's a risk of cursing

Comment: The comments on the other answer state that you can get cursed items, even on first usage.